# How to Stop Calender to convert to AM_PM format

Tags: android, calendar

I am working i a app in which i am getting, hr,min,day,month and year. now i have to **convert **it inTo **miliseconds**.
i have used **Calender** class to do so.
But my **Problem** is **Calender is converting it into AM_PM format** which is causing error.

See my method.

```
 public static long getTimeStamp(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int min) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    Log.d(Const.TAG, "getTimeStamp: " + c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
    return (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
}
```

now if i set 14 as hour. it converts it into 02. how to fix this. thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want exactly. . Can you explain in brief @xbadal

Comment: int day, int month, int year, int hour, int min, i have these individual fields, now i want it to convert into millisecond. see my method above. i am using calender class. it i set hour to 14 it is converted into 2. i wanna restrict it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public static long getTimeStamp(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int min) {

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month,day, 
                    hour, min, 0);
        long miliseconds = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
return miliseconds;

}
```

Comment: Welcome.. @xbadal

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
```

Like this :

```
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to convert into Milliseconds.